# find and replace object from list with certain attribute already not exists

Tags: java, list

I have a List where some Objects are being stored.I would like  to remove an object from list with certain attribute already not exists.My sample code is, here please help me.

```
public class Mysamples {

    private void example() {
        List<SomeType> listWithDuplicates = new ArrayList<SomeType>();

        SomeType someObject1 = new SomeType("hello", "1");
        SomeType someObject2 = new SomeType("hello", "2");
 }

private void removeDuplicates(List<SomeType> listWithDuplicates) {
    /* Set of all attributes seen so far */
    Set<String> attributes = new HashSet<String>();
    /* All confirmed duplicates go in here */
    List duplicates = new ArrayList<SomeType>();

    for (SomeType x : listWithDuplicates) {
        if (attributes.contains(x.getName())) 
        {
            duplicates.add(x);
        }
        attributes.add(x.getName());
    }

    System.out.println(duplicates);
   // System.out.println(attributes);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    List<SomeType> listWithDuplicates = new ArrayList<SomeType>();
    SomeType someObject1 = new SomeType("hello", "1");
    SomeType someObject2 = new SomeType("hello", "2");
    SomeType someObject3 = new SomeType("hello", "1");
    SomeType someObject4 = new SomeType("hello1", "2");
    SomeType someObject5 = new SomeType("hello1", "1");
    SomeType someObject6 = new SomeType("hello2", "2");


    listWithDuplicates.add(someObject1);
    listWithDuplicates.add(someObject2);
    listWithDuplicates.add(someObject3);
    listWithDuplicates.add(someObject4);
    listWithDuplicates.add(someObject5);
    listWithDuplicates.add(someObject6);
    Mysamples s = new Mysamples();

    s.removeDuplicates(listWithDuplicates);
}
}
```

****The out put is****

```
[SomeType{name=hello, id=2}, SomeType{name=hello, id=1}, SomeType{name=hello1, id=1}]
```

**but i want the out put like**

```
[SomeType{name=hello, id=1,SomeType{name=hello, id=2}, SomeType{name=hello, id=1}} SomeType{name=hello1, id=2},SomeType{name=hello1, id=1}]]
```

Comment: It is not clear, what you are trying to achieve

Comment: My resultant list contain  objects less than one as actual number of objects

Comment: Then what is the criteria for not adding that one result? and How would decide which item to add when the list being added is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have done  it in another way

private void removeDuplicates(List listWithDuplicates) {

```
    List<SomeType> list = null;
    Map<Object, List<SomeType>> map = new HashMap<Object, List<SomeType>>();
    for (SomeType x : listWithDuplicates) {
        if (map.get(x.getName()) != null) {
            map.get(x.getName()).add(x);
        } else {
            list = new ArrayList<SomeType>();
            list.add(x);
            map.put(x.getName(), list);
        }
    }
    List<SomeType> listWithOutDuplicates = new ArrayList<SomeType>();
    for (Entry<Object, List<SomeType>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue().size() > 1) {
            for (SomeType someType : entry.getValue()) {
                listWithOutDuplicates.add(someType);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(listWithOutDuplicates);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is only going to find duplicates *after* encountering a name for the first time.  So, for example, the first "hello" is not in the attributes set, so you add it (but it is not considered a duplicate), then the next two "hello" entries are considered duplicates and are added to the duplicates list.  The same for "hello1".  If you want to find all duplicates, that includes the first time they are encountered, you will have to do two passes over the collection.  First to collect all of the names in the attributes set, then again to flag all of the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void removeDuplicates(List<SomeType> listWithDuplicates) {
    Map<String, Integer> nameCountMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    // get count of each name
    for (SomeType x : listWithDuplicates) {
        Integer count = nameCountMap.get(x.getName());
        if (count == null) {
            count = new Integer(0);
        }
        count++;
        nameCountMap.put(x.getName(), count);
    }
    // Print duplicates
    for (SomeType x : listWithDuplicates) {
        if (nameCountMap.get(x.getName()) > 1) {
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be over doing it but still..

1. Define a Comparator something like following:-

   public NameComparator implements Comparator{

   ```
      public int compare(SomeType x, SomeType y){
         if(x.getName()==null){   // you want this field to be missing or null right?
               return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
         }
         else if(y.getName()==null){
             return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
         }else{
               return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
         }
      }
   ```

   }
2. Instead of using List, use TreeSet using the above comparator.

   TreeSet sortedSet = new TreeSet(new NameComparator ());
3. Now add items to the above set.
4. Now, if present the object you are looking for can be fetched using sortedSet.first().
   [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#first%28%29)